# Booting Windows 7 in Boot Camp shows a black screen with a blinking cursor

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, dmg

I am trying to restore a DMG image of a Windows 7 Boot Camp partition back to Boot Camp. (I know that I should have used Winclone, but I didn't have that option because the drive was already dying and so I couldn't even access OS X anymore.)

So far, I've gotten to the point where I can start up the computer, hold Option, choose Windows, but then when it boots up, it shows a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I've tried a few things so far to try and fix this, none of which has worked. I have used the Windows 7 install DVD to run `bootrec` and all its possible arguments. I've ran `chkdsk C: /b`. I've also used the "Automatically fix startup problems" button, of course, as well.

Anyone know what else I could try to fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem after resizing my disk partitions.
This breaks bootcamp.
I found a way to solve this, I googled and had to do something very elaborate in terminal. Don't remember the details sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an Image-File frome a previous (working) Bootcamp Installation it should not be necessary, but there is an upgrade for the graphics and bluetooth driver from Apple with an installation instruction found [here "Boot Camp: iMac displays a black screen during installation of Windows 7"](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3173) which adresses this problem.